# No Primary or candidate keys in the referenced table that match column list in foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, sql-server-2016, ddl

I am trying to create a few basic SQL tables however I keep getting the following error:

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'CART' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK__ORDERS__CART_ID__2B3F6F97'

This is the current code which I am using.

```
create table USERS
(
    User_ID int NOT NULL primary key,
    Address varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    Email varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    Password varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    Phone varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    F_Name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    L_Name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    Date_of_Birth varchar(30) NOT NULL
)

create table PAYMENT
(
    User_ID int NOT NULL primary key,
    Credit_Card varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    Debit_Card varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    Google_Pay varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    Apple_Pay varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    Paypal varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    foreign key (User_ID)
    references USERS(User_ID)
)

create table CART
(
    User_ID int NOT NULL,
    Cart_ID int NOT NULL,
    Total_Price float NOT NULL,
    primary key (Cart_ID, User_ID),
    foreign key(User_ID)
    references USERS(User_ID)
)

create table ORDERS
(
    Order_ID int NOT NULL primary key,
    Total_Price float NOT NULL,
    Payment_Method varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    User_ID int NOT NULL,
    CART_ID int NOT NULL,
    foreign key (User_ID)
    references USERS(User_ID),
    foreign key (Cart_ID)
    references CART(Cart_ID),
)

create table ORDER_HISTORY
(
    User_ID int NOT NULL,
    Order_ID int NOT NULL,
    primary key (User_ID, Order_ID),
    foreign key (User_ID)
    references USERS(User_ID),
    foreign key (Order_ID)
    references ORDERS(Order_ID)
)
```

I have tried modifying things and moving them around but cannot get the error to go away. I suspect that this is probably quite simple and obvious but since I am so new to SQL I am probably missing it.

Comment: Payment should have paymentid as primary key, cart should have cartid. The latter one will fix your error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As table `CART` has composite primary key, then you should to reference to a composite primary key:

```
 create table ORDERS
(
    Order_ID int NOT NULL primary key,
    Total_Price float NOT NULL,
    Payment_Method varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    User_ID int NOT NULL,
    CART_ID int NOT NULL,
    foreign key (User_ID)
    references USERS(User_ID),
    foreign key (Cart_ID, User_ID)
    references CART(Cart_ID, User_ID),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

`cart` has a composite primary key `(cart_id, order_id)`. Each of these columns aren't primary keys independently, just their combination. The foreign key from `orders` should act the same - you should have a single foreign key based on the combination of the two:

```
create table ORDERS
(
    Order_ID int NOT NULL primary key,
    Total_Price float NOT NULL,
    Payment_Method varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    User_ID int NOT NULL,
    CART_ID int NOT NULL,
    foreign key (User_ID)
    references USERS(User_ID),
    foreign key (Cart_ID, User_id) -- here
    references CART(Cart_ID, User_id),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In table Cart, you need to define Cart_ID with PRIMARY KEY. If for some reason you cannot or don't want to define a PRIMARY KEY then try UNIQUE KEY constraint on the same column.

Answer (score 0):

It is the Primary Key on the Cart table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CART](
    [User_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Cart_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Total_Price] [float] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__CART__D6AB58B9B18E85A5] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [User_ID] ASC,
    [Cart_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CART]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([User_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[USERS] ([User_ID])
```